# How to use CI and doxygen to know only if new code is well documented

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, doxygen

I have a very old c++ project. This project is not completely documented and with my colleagues we have decided to document the new code of this project. So my question is:

Is there a way for Doxygen to fail in CI (as the same way as WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED and WARN_AS_ERROR options) but only for new code added ?

Comment: You can run it on the selected files : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260536/4165552 ; There doesn't seem to be any option to select particular lines from a single source file, so you need to improvise from here.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? No there is no such option as doxygen has no idea about what is added compared to the previous time (doxygen is not a compiler, but compilers don't know this, to the best of my knowledge, either).