# Doxygen rerun on selected files

Tags: doxygen

I have large number of includes and only one path is changing for each projects, this is causing lot of runtime. Is there a way in doxygen where I get to keep the initially generated files and only rerun the doxygen on new added path, this will save a lot of runtime.

Comment: This is not possible as due to the changed paths links can change etc. Some optimization is done (images) other possibilities might be tag files. See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203172/how-to-get-doxygen-to-run-faster ad other questions about "incremental runs for doxygen".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doxygen is Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247189/doxygen-is-slow)